# How would I compare two dates in a form and validate them? The second one shouldn't be before the first one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation

I am trying to build a form in React with Bootstrap. I have two dates (one is when you started to work and the other is when you ended to work for company), the second one shouldn't be before the first one. So if the first one is 10.1.2020, you shoudn't be able to choose the date in the second one that is before this date.

As is a react app, I am also giving you a link: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-worker-nwtgu?file=/package.json

Code that I am interested in is inside these components: Practical and PracticalForm.

Code of form:

```
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicDateFrom">
          <Form.Label>Worked from</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            onChange={(e) => {
              checkDate(e);
              handleChange(e);
            }}
            type="date"
            defaultValue={dateFrom}
            name="dateFrom"
            required
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicDateUntil">
          <Form.Label>Worked to</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            isInvalid={validate}
            onChange={(e) => {
              checkDate(e);
              handleChange(e);
            }}
            // onChange={(e) => {
            //   handleChange(e);
            //   checkDate();
            // }}
            type="date"
            defaultValue={dateTo}
            name="dateTo"
            required
          />
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
            Date must be later then date from when you worked...
          </Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Form.Group>
```

And the function I validate with, now looks like this:

```
checkDate = (event) => {
    let d1 = new Date(this.state.dateFrom);
    let d2 = new Date(this.state.dateTo);

    if (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime()) {
      this.setState({
        validate: false,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        validate: true,
      });
    }
    console.log(d1.getTime());
    console.log(d2.getTime());
    console.log(this.state.validate);
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the `checkDate(event)` function inside `this.setState` of `handleChange` function because the things acts async here so while setting the state you can call the `checkDate(event)` like,

```
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      },
      () => {
        this.checkDate(event);
      }
    );
  };
```

Then modify the `checkDate` function like,

```
  checkDate = async (event) => {
    let d1 = new Date(this.state.dateFrom);
    let d2 = new Date(this.state.dateTo);

    if (d1.getTime() < d2.getTime()) {
      this.setState({
        validate: false
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        validate: true
      });
    }
    console.log(d1.getTime());
    console.log(d2.getTime());
    console.log(this.state.validate);
  };
```

Also change the condition,

`d1.getTime() > d2.getTime()` **to** `d1.getTime() < d2.getTime()` as `d1` date should be lesser than `d2` date always...

[image: Edit red-moon-1e7ri]

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't work as intended. Does it work for you? Is it possible to maybe run checkDate after the state is updated?

Is the `checkDate()`function okey? And the principe to do this.

Comment: @Emilija, You also need to update few other things.. Please move the ```checkDate``` inside the ```handleChange``` function. Also the cindition needs to be like ```d1.getTime() < d2.getTime()```... Updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-leftpad-c18sk

Comment: @Emilija, Updated the answer with new solution and hope this should solve your issue..